# java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java

This is a part of my program's sample run that shows an error.

```
Please enter your the number of your selection : 5
Enter the blood Type : b
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Hospital.getNumberOfPatientsBlood(Hospital.java:136)
at Hospital.main(Hospital.java:71)
```

I have this error, and I don't know what's wrong. It should give me a message that says there is a zero patient has a blood type of B.

This is the part that it shows the error:

The method:

```
   public static int getNumberOfPatientsBlood( String bloodT ){

  int bloodTypeCount=0;
  for (int j =0; j<hospitalPatient.length;j++){

     if (hospitalPatient[j].equals(bloodT))
        bloodTypeCount++;

     else

        continue; 

  }
  return -1 ;

   }
```

The other error is in the main:

```
        case 5:
           input.nextLine();              
           System.out.print("Enter the blood Type : ");
           String searchBloodType = input.nextLine();

           if (getNumberOfPatientsBlood(searchBloodType)!=-1)
              System.out.println("the total number of patients having the same Blood Type: "+getNumberOfPatientsBlood(searchBloodType));

           break;
```

Comment: how are you populating your `hospitalPatient` array?

Comment: Have you initialized your hospitalPatient data structure?

Answer (score 0):

I guess hospitalPatient is null, initialize it first.